# BadValue, error: SC3020. The SQL query text exceeded the maximum limit of 544720 characters in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB shell, and when I perform the QUERY, I receive the error: The SQL query text exceeded the maximum limit of 544720 characters in Azure CosmosDB. In my collections i have 1-10m records.all these fields that i use in the filter are indexed.

My query is the following:

```js
db.Actions.aggregate([{$match:{type:{$in:["registration","fillform"]}}},{$lookup:{from:"Visits",localField:"value",foreignField:"token",as:"Visit"}},{$unwind:"$Visit"},{$match:{"Visit.url":{$regex:/path=testtest/}}},{$group:{_id:{Date:{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d",date:"$date"}},ActionType:"$type"},Count:{$sum:1}}},{$project:{_id:0,Date:"$_id.Date",ActionType:"$_id.ActionType",Count:1}}])
```

the source C# code via mongo driver the following:

```cs
   var actions = await _dbContext.Actions
                    .Aggregate()
                    .Match(actionsFilter)
                    .Lookup<Action, Visit, ActionLookedUp>(_dbContext.Visits,
                    (Action output) => output.Value,
                    (Visit visit) => visit.Token,
                    (ActionLookedUp output) => output.Visits)
                    .Match(visitsFilter)
                    .Group(x => new { new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, x.Date.Day), Type = x.Type }, g => new { g.Key, g.Key.Type, Count = g.Count() })
                    .ToListAsync();
```

the response is also can not be more than 10 or even 50mb, because as you can see i use Group

As you can see this query is not too long (just filter, lookup, and group and that’s it) I need to receive groups with count, but I receive the Error. How can I fix it?

Mongo version 4.2

RU/s : 10.000

P.S. I also receive the same result even i add .Limit(1) after the lookup

Comment: That's not a trivial query. Maybe your `unwind` is producing something enormous, in preparation for the next stage? Have you tried to isolate the issue by removing parts of your query, to figure out where it breaks? Also: RU/sec doesn't really matter, for a single query (a query will still complete, even if you exceed allotted RU - you'll just be in "RU debt" for a period of time afterward).

Comment: yeah, the same result without unwind. And everything works without lookup at all. But with lookup i get badvalue